# copy tree structure with gradle & subprojects

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am using build.gradle to build a project and three subProjects.
like:

master/

build.gradle

settings.gradle

subProjectA/

subProjectB/

subProjectC/

I am trying to copy a tree structure from subProjectA and paste it in subProjectB & subProjectC. No new files or directories get created in the directory "B" in subProjectB or subProjectC.

I tried to do that a couple different ways, but I have not been successful.

Here is what I have tried:

```
eclipse {
copy {
from { rootProject.project('subProjectA')
include 'src/B/C/D/**/**'
}
into 'src/B/web/rest/'
}
```

}

```
eclipse {   
copy {
from { rootProject.project('subProjectA')
include "src/ B/C/" 
include '**/**'
include '**/**/**'
include '**/**/**/**/'       
}   
into 'src/B/web/rest/'
}
```

}

```
eclipse.copy (todir: 'src/main/web/rest'){
fileset("rootProject.project('subProjectA')/src/B/C/**/**/**")
}
```

I have also tried to add this to the task "build", but that had the same outcome.

Inside the rootProjects build.gradle I have a section for each subProject.  For example:

project ('subProjectB') { ...

Wrote the eclipse task description in there.

I should also state that rootProject & the subProjects are identified in settings.gradle.
The reason for subProjectB & subProjectC to be linked to subProjectA is they use subProjectA as one of their dependencies.  This way subProjectB & subProjectC would be linked to changes whenever they happen and I would not have apply the changes to subProjectB & subProjectC individually.

what am I am missing?

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Comment: The snippets contain several mistakes, but why do you need to copy sources around in the first place? Which bigger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: he reason for subProjectB & subProjectC to be linked to subProjectA is they use subProjectA as one of their dependencies. This way subProjectB & subProjectC would be linked to changes whenever they happen and I would not have apply the changes to subProjectB & subProjectC individually.

Comment: Copying sources around isn't a good solution for this. If B and C use A's code, they should declare project dependencies on A.

Comment: being the write choice or not is not my choice, because I am not the project lead.

Comment: what is eclipse or eclipse.copy or etc... missing?

Comment: It's a fundamentally wrong approach, and the implementation is fundamentally wrong too. I recommend to study the first several chapters of the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the samples in the full Gradle distribution.